# How python calculates the size of text files

Tags: python, numpy

I use the following code to save to text file:

```
filepath = open(filename, 'a')
np.savetxt(filepath, C, fmt='%i')
```

I came from `C` where I can control the size of the resulting file and know in advance. Hence, I want to understand how the size of the file is calculated in Python. My program generates a `numpy` matrix of shape (12500, 65) **containing values 1 or -1**. The resulting text file on disk has the (`2,024,874` bytes) which does not make sense to me! Isn't supposed to be calculated as (assuming the size of a signed integer is `8` as I explicitly mention it as `fmt='%i'`): `12500 * 65 * 8 = 6,500,000  bytes'?

Comment: I suspect that %i translates to 32-bit integers, which means your calculation is off by a factor of 2.

Comment: What exact name do you use for `filepath`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Does it matter? It is a combination of text, number, and special characters

Comment: It matters if it ends with `.gz`.

Comment: Did you look at the resulting file? You're saving in *text* format: a small number will need fewer (decimal) digits than a larger number. There's no basis for assuming 8 bytes per entry.

Comment: @MadPhysicist [`savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) accepts an open file object.

Comment: @MadPhysicist from the documentation you linked, the first argument can be either a filename or file handle.

Comment: @NickT. You are absolutely right. I did not read carefully.

Comment: ... but with Python 3, I find I have to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. I was not aware of that

Comment: @MarkDickinson Right. The matrix contains values 1 or -1 only

Comment: So then you should expect 2 bytes per "1" entry (one byte for the character "1", and one byte for a space or newline separator following it) and 3 bytes per "-1" (same as for "1", but with an extra character for the minus sign), so about 2.5 bytes per entry on average if your 1s and -1s are approximately evenly distributed. And indeed `2.5 * 12500 * 65` gives `2031250`, which isn't far off the number of bytes you're seeing.

Comment: Try it with `'%7i'` (7 char per number, plus one for the delimiter).  What formatting do you use in `C` (that allows you to control the file size).

Comment: Oh, and if you're on Windows it's probably 2 characters per line-ending rather than one, but I can't be certain about that, and don't have a Windows machine handy to check.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misconception.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Mark, you're saving *text*, i.e. `"1"`, not `\x01\x00...`. To demonstrate:

```
import io
import numpy as np

tenbyten = np.ones((10, 10), dtype=int)

myfile = io.BytesIO()
np.savetxt(myfile, tenbyten, fmt='%i')
len(myfile.getvalue()) # 200
myfile.getvalue()[:30] # b'1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n1 1 1 1 1 '
```

It's a string of ASCII number 1's and spaces, with newlines. Yours has some `-`'s mixed in I gather. If you want *pure* binary, you could do something like the following:

```
raw_data = tenbyten.tobytes() # .tofile() to go to a file instead of bytestring
len(raw_data) # 800
raw_data[:10] # b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
```

To get something that matches your 6.5 MB as an exercise, you could do the following: `len(np.empty((12500, 65), dtype='int64').tobytes())` Note that the raw data is *very* raw, and discards all information about the data type, endianness, and shape, so the following is true:

```
np.ones((10, 10)).tobytes() == np.ones((5, 20)).tobytes() == np.ones(100).tobytes()
```

If you use `np.save`, that will save binary with the metadata

```
my_npy = io.BytesIO()
np.save(my_npy, tenbyten)
len(my_npy.getbuffer()) # 880
my_npy.getvalue()[:70]
# b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00F\x00{'descr': '<i8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (10, 10), "
```

For your case with +1/-1, forcing a datatype of `int8` (with `my_array.astype('int8')`) is basically a free 8-fold data compression.